# control for report viewer in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, reportviewer, deepzoom

i want to write a report viewer control that has the effects like deepzoom(zoomin,animation effects) control.
especially like this control 
           http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/evidence/
can anyone provide the startup kits or any links that help to start with it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is PivotViewer Control. You can learn its architecture, look at samples and download [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/pivot-viewer/pivotviewer-control)